# how to pass XML setAttribute in php foreach

Tags: php, xml

I want to generate XML for an array which has many field and i want to set that fields in a single XML element as attributes of that element below is my php code.

```
<?php
$rs=array();//values come in $rs from database, it has many fields
$doc = new DOMDocument(); 
$doc->formatOutput = true; 
$root = $doc->createElement( "slides" ); 
$doc->appendChild( $root );
$firstchild = $doc->createElement( "device" ); 
$fs=$doc->appendChild( $firstchild );
foreach( $rs as $key=>$value ){           
    $fs->setAttribute($key,$value);
}
$xml_string = $doc->saveXML();
echo $xml_string;
```

But this is not working for me, it gives me an error like:

**DOMElement:setAttribute() expects parameter 2 to be string,array given**

> My $rs array structure is like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => dfd
            [width] => 2
            [height] => 1
            [resolution] => 
            [space] => 
        )

)
```

, i want output like:

```
<slides>
    <device id="12" name="mydevice" color="red" .....and so on></device>
</slides>
```

Comment: Remove `$doc->appendChild($fs);` after foreach

Comment: https://eval.in/601047 -

Comment: still facing the same error "DOMElement:setAttribute() expects parameter 2 to be string,array given"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did some mistakes, the main of them that you appendchild element to Document but not to parent

```
$doc = new DOMDocument(); 
$doc->formatOutput = true;

$root = $doc->createElement( "slides" ); 
$doc->appendChild( $root );

$fs = $doc->createElement( "device" ); 
$root->appendChild( $fs );

foreach( $rs as $key=>$value ){           
    $fs->setAttribute($key,$value);
}

$xml_string = $doc->saveXML();
echo $xml_string;
```

[working example](https://eval.in/601047)

Comment: still facing same problem: DOMElement:setAttribute() expects parameter 2 to be string,array given

Comment: @vishal change in foreach `rs` to `rs[0]`

Comment: but what if i have $rs[1] as well? what should i do??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116542/discussion-between-vishal-and-splash58).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create each attribute and assign it to the correct node, something like this:

```
foreach( $rs as $key => $value ){
    $attrib=$doc->createAttribute($key);
    $attrib->nodeValue=$value;
    $fs->appendChild( $attrib );    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The $rs variable is an array of the records with an array of the fields as an element. So you need two nested loops.

The outer loop iterates the records and creates an `device` element node for each record. The inner loop iterates the fields and adds the attributes.

```
$rs = [
  [ 
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'dfd',
    'width' => 2,
    'height' => 1,
    'resolution' => '',
    'space' => ''
  ]
];

$document = new DOMDocument(); 

$slides = $document->appendChild(
  $document->createElement("slides")
);

foreach ($rs as $record) {
  $device = $slides->appendChild(
    $document->createElement("device")
  );
  foreach($record as $key => $value){           
    $device->setAttribute($key,$value);
  }
}

$document->formatOutput = true;
echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<slides>
  <device id="1" name="dfd" width="2" height="1" resolution="" space=""/>
</slides>
```